# 0xDBE How to disable scema scan on startup

Tags: datagrip

I'm trying to use 0xdbe to connect a huge database.
Problem is, that on startup it starts to scan DB schema, locking db and preventing it access from outside. Full scan takes a lot of time(more than an hour) so, it's absolutely impossible to do on prod database.

I managed to connect to dev database(at night when there was no load), and after that it caches that data somewhere and works really fast.

Is there any option, to disable this scan, or make it less aggressive?

Where this data is stored, how frequently it's updated.

Is it possible to scan everything once, write it to some file, and import on machines of other developers?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Seeing as 0xDBE is still in development it might be worth raising it as a feature request to the JetBrains guys? They're pretty open user ideas.

Comment: @JoeMighty Thank you for bringing attention to this question. I've got an answer from developers on intellij devforum, and I've posted it below.

Answer (score 3):

I've got an reply on question in dev forum, from **Andrey Dernov**. I'll summarize it here:

About slowliness of synchronisation, there is a related issue in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-137). And intellij team said, that they have implemented new DB introspection which will increase the performance in this regard.

And all caches are located in `.idea` folder under the `~/.0xDBE10/config/projects/<your_project_name>`.
It is possible to share dataSources.ids and dataSources.xml files from there, to speed-up process for other developers in team.

Comment: Great! I did notice that more recent versions of 0xDBE have been faster at syncronising database schemas but didn't know whether it was because just the fact I was using a different database. Thanks for replying though.